# Uint to binary transfer

Tags: c#, binary

This may be a stupid question for some of you but I need to ask. 
I have this problem and i could not figure it out. If someone has any idea i will be glad if you'd share it with me. 
I have a UInt64 that i have to convert to binary and split it on groups by 5 bits. 
And then set a different value depending on each group of bits.
My problem is that I can't figure out a good way to transfer it to groups of 5 bits.

After that i will asign for each group a different value. For example:

```
00000 - 0
00001 - a
00010 - B
00011 - c
00100 - d
.......
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

And what is going to be the best way to change the value later? I was thinking about a Switch

```
Switch()
{
case "00000" : return 0;
case "00001" : return a;
case "00010" : return B;
case "00011" : return c;
}
```

Here is a little more explanation what i want to get is this. For example i have the `64Uint = 1234123;`
From it i want to get the following array:

```
 Array[,] something = new Array[12,5];
```

Comment: As i said i have no idea how to break it down to binary. That is why i`m asking here. I have idea what to do after that with it but i cant figure out how to break it down.

Comment: What do you mean by groups of **5** bytes? A UInt64 consists of 8 bytes. And your example shows groups of **4** bits.

Comment: Sorry i ment bits i need to make 12 groups each by 5 bits from each 64Uint.

Comment: It seems like you want [base-64 encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bitmasks to split the uint64 in groups of five bits:

```
UInt64 a = 1234;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i += 5)
{
    uint fiveBits = (uint)((a >> i) & 31);
    // fiveBits is between 0 and 31
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [BitConverter.GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx) to convert a Uint64 to bytes.